# Cannot Open Azure VM (Ubuntu 18.04) Port

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, port, nmap

Running the jupyter notebook server on port 8888 on the virtual machine. Trying to use port forward to my desktop (running Linux Mint). The server is running on the VM alright, but the port is closed to my desktop. A network sweep gives the following results.

```
della@clevo-workstation:~$ sudo nmap -sT -O 20.184.1.17
[sudo] password for della:                
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-10-01 15:51 +08
Nmap scan report for 20.184.1.17
Host is up (0.0077s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
8000/tcp closed http-alt
8888/tcp closed sun-answerbook
```

I have no clue what is the sun answerbook thing, and why is that port closed. I have already opened that from azure inbound port rule.

For further information, the virtual machine has service like redis running on its port 6379 too, which I can use from my laptop. But even that is not showing in the nmap.

Answer (score 0):

Run `netstat -antop | grep 8888` which will give you the process ID that is running on that port, which you can then use to find out what is actually running. "sun-answerbook" is just what namp has in it's list of what application first used that port when it was created, it is not accurate.